# Создание проектов VB6 в MVS2015 и более поздних

Tags: visual-studio, visual-basic

Собственно вопрос заключается в том, реально ли создать проект VB6.0 в современном MVS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напрямую - нет, нельзя.

Можно попробовать работать с VB6 через расширение [Visual Basic Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/00cc8ff8-beb3-4f08-8aa6-59eefba3bb40), но полноценной поддержки и работоспособности вам никто не гарантирует.

Comment: Спасибо, а сталкивались ли Вы с проблемой:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3812,5): error MSB3030: не удалось скопировать файл "obj\Debug\StandardExeProject1.exe" - файл не найден.
Сборка проекта "StandardExeProject1.vb6proj" завершена с ошибкой.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик. нет. смотрите логи билда в output. но я вообще сомневаюсь, что воскрешать VB6 - это хорошая идея. Проще поставить его на виртуалку.

Comment: Логично, спасибо.